# How to add an API in azure API management service., which is not "azure API hosted"

Tags: api, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

So i only got the link for the API , like https://xyz.azurewebsites.net/api/product. And i want to add it to the API management service and also want to test it out by sending a GET request.I tried out these options to add the APIs by OpenAPI , WADL and WSDL.But faced an error like "cant able to parse the file".I dont have any knowledge about APIs and now i am stuck.What can be the solution to this issue? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should use Add a new API from App Service

[image]

Also as I know you should have an option to link API Management from your App Service

Comment: so you mean any API hosted , like this "https://xyz.azurewebsites.net/api/product" will be listed down in the option you mentioned above.But what if i am not able to find the api which i want to add.How will i be able to add it?

Comment: I hope you will see your App Service name.